# $_POST is empty in WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm posting form data using `method="POST"` to another page in a WordPress. But, the `$_POST` is empty and `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` is also empty.

```
<form action="?page_id=1814"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
    <input type="radio" name="Search_opt" value="keywrd" />
    <select id="tmp" name="key1" onchange="SetText(key1,word1)">
        <option selected="selected" value="abcd">abc</option>
        <option value="efg">EFG</option>
    </select> : 
    <input id="tmp1" type="text" name="word1"  size="30" /> 
    <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />     
    <input type="Submit" value="Search" /> 
</form>
```

and another page contains

```
<div id="Results">
<?php 
    print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
    print $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']. "<BR />";
    print_r($_POST);
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
</div>
```

gives output

```
CONTENT_TYPE: 
CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Array ( ) array(0) { }
```

Same scripts work fine in HTML pages but not in WordPress. What may be the possible reason?

Comment: Is that the litteral copy-pasted output? It's strange that it says "CONTENT_TYPE" twice, and that the `REQUEST_METHOD` is not outputted...

Comment: you are post the form in same page?

Comment: @Ivar: sorry its error while copying. 
CONTENT_TYPE:            Array ( ) array(0) { }.  REQUEST_METHOD is also empty